# large MySQL table, any downsides to using MEMORY/HEAP

Tags: mysql

I have a table with approx 120M records and 1.5Gb in size. This table is read only (it will never be written to) and it can be refilled from an external source at any time. So a restart of MySQL will not be a problem.

Is there any reason why I shouldn't use a MEMORY storage engine for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not. And if you are only doing reads then you should be fine.

I have run tables of this size, and as long as your server can take it then you should be ok. If anything it would save wear and tear on your HDD(s) in the long run.

I have done things similar to this and not had any trouble.

Comment: +1 agree with @FaddishWorm. I have worked with offline `MEMORY` tables having 4 to 8 GB size and never faced any problems like loss of data or any other issues.

Answer (score 2):

You should measure the **startup time** (including population of the table). Otherwise **memory**'s the limit (cost of memory and matching server hardware). Measure that as well.

Comment: +1 if you are using read only MEMORY tables on servers having live traffic, then you may need to set proper delay in traffic using `load balancer` after restarting server.

Comment: Memory isn't a big issue and population of the table does take some time (5 min) but a restart is not happening very often and it's not a huge problem if the table is empty for a few minutes.

Comment: your other queries using this table might get locked while populating the data in `MEMORY` table(for 5 mins).

Comment: @Omesh, True, but I'm using a tmp table for that and renaming/dropping it once it's populated.

Comment: that's great! then it should not be a problem!